# Validate custom form in ez publish 5?

Tags: ezpublish

I would to know , how to validate custom form values in ez publish 5?
any help or links to topics would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to the site. This question is too general to get a useful answer. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

If the form is a custom Symfony Form, then eZ Platform doesn't provide anything special for it. You must configure validation for your form the way you would with Symfony alone.

If the custom form is related to content, then I need more details in order to answer.

Comment: Thank`s for replay Bertrand Dunogier, 
My form is simply  HTML form  and i have controller, i get data in my controller. in this controller i get data with **$this->request->get()** method , now i want  validate this data   (example: if value  is empty or if value is integer or string and etc).

if you want  more  information just ask me

Comment: Then I suggest you use Symfony Forms, by-the-book. It has everything you need, including native validation support by means of annotations or configuration: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html.

Comment: OK i will look up to this link provided by you, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer code from eZ Platform Demo Bundle for Form processing:
https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform-demo/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Controller/ContactFormController.php